# Identifiers starting with an integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, identifier

I have a .net dll and when I add it in the references, it goes without any issue. The problem is that its namespaces start with an integer e.g. **3gppsa5.org.AlarmIRPSystem** and when I try to use or import it, the intelliSense doesn't allow and says **identifier expected**.

I don't have the source of this library so I can't change it. I know it is compiled and the Object Browser is correctly showing all of its classes and functions. However, I am unable to use it in my code. Is there any way to use it in VB .NET

I've tried using Reflection, but found many problems. I want to declare the variable something like;

```
Dim MyIRP As 3gppsa5.org.AlarmIRPSystem.AlarmIRP
```

Is there any way to achieve this without using reflection and having complete intellisense support.

Thanks.

Comment: i wonder which language permits using namespaces like that. except IL.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. This identifier is not CLS compliant. Non-CLS compliant identifiers are not guaranteed to be usable in other .NET languages.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would be *really* dubious of such as an assembly... using such a poor choice of namespace doesn't reflect well on the design decisions of the developer. I suggest you either find an alternative, or get in contact with the developer/vendor and as for a more sensible namespace.

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference. VB is pretty much like C# in this sense. Identifiers should not start with a number.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Fair enough - will remove that part :)

Comment: In SQL server I've seen identifiers like the one I need, in square brackets. Even spaces could also go in them. Is some similar syntax available for .NET as well? Or some compiler settings? The dll was compiled, that suggests that the compilation bypassed it some way.

Comment: @Saad: You can use identifiers which are also keywords, but I don't *think* there's any way of using an identifier which starts with a number. I really *wouldn't* try to work around this though: I'd get it fixed. Using identifiers like this (however they built it) is really bad form on the part of the developer responsible.